# splitting returned sql rows onto multiple new table rows every two rows

Tags: php, mysql

I currently have six categories lists in one table that i am currently displaying using the below code. So below i am displaying all six categories and the records within them.

I am using the same code three times, so the first set displays the first two categories, the second set shows the third and fourth categories and the final set of code shows categories five and six.

What i would like to do is just have one set of the below code instead of three which will display all of my categories with two on each row as opposed to me manually having to alter the below code to accommodate me adding and removing categories.

How would i go about achieving this as the best i can do is to get all the categories to appear on one row, how would i split it so i can choose every two categories to go onto a new row so i can have unlimited categories appear without having to change the code to accommodate them all the time ?

```
        $uid = get_current_user_id();
        $stn_added_by = "";




    echo "<table class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tr>";
    $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID, category FROM knowledgebase_category ORDER BY category LIMIT 2");
    while ($row3 = $sql3->fetch_assoc()){

    $kbc_ID = $row3['ID'];
    $kbc_category = $row3['category'];

    echo "<td width='50%' valign='top'><h4 class='heading'>" . $row3['category'];
    echo "</h4><br><table class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
    $sql3a = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT kb_ID, kb_subject FROM knowledgebase_items WHERE kb_visible = 'Yes' and kb_category = '$kbc_ID' ORDER BY kb_subject LIMIT 5");
    while ($row3a = $sql3a->fetch_assoc()){

    echo "<tr><td width='50%'><blockquote class='message'><a class='hover' href='" . $row3a['kb_ID'] . "'>" . $row3a['kb_subject'] . "</a></blockquote></td></tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr><td width='50%'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward' aria-hidden='true'></span> <a class='hover' href='category-" . $kbc_ID . "'>View All Items</a><br><br></td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";








    echo "<table class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tr>";
    $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID, category FROM knowledgebase_category ORDER BY category LIMIT 2,2");
    while ($row3 = $sql3->fetch_assoc()){

    $kbc_ID = $row3['ID'];
    $kbc_category = $row3['category'];

    echo "<td width='50%' valign='top'><h4 class='heading'>" . $row3['category'];
    echo "</h4><br><table class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
    $sql3a = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT kb_ID, kb_subject FROM knowledgebase_items WHERE kb_visible = 'Yes' and kb_category = '$kbc_ID' ORDER BY kb_subject LIMIT 5");
    while ($row3a = $sql3a->fetch_assoc()){

    echo "<tr><td width='50%'><blockquote class='message'><a class='hover' href='" . $row3a['kb_ID'] . "'>" . $row3a['kb_subject'] . "</a></blockquote></td></tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr><td width='50%'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward' aria-hidden='true'></span> <a class='hover' href='category-" . $kbc_ID . "'>View All Items</a><br><br></td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";







    echo "<table class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'><tr>";
    $sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID, category FROM knowledgebase_category ORDER BY category LIMIT 4,2");
    while ($row3 = $sql3->fetch_assoc()){

    $kbc_ID = $row3['ID'];
    $kbc_category = $row3['category'];

    echo "<td width='50%' valign='top'><h4 class='heading'>" . $row3['category'];
    echo "</h4><br><table class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
    $sql3a = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT kb_ID, kb_subject FROM knowledgebase_items WHERE kb_visible = 'Yes' and kb_category = '$kbc_ID' ORDER BY kb_subject LIMIT 5");
    while ($row3a = $sql3a->fetch_assoc()){

    echo "<tr><td width='50%'><blockquote class='message'><a class='hover' href='" . $row3a['kb_ID'] . "'>" . $row3a['kb_subject'] . "</a></blockquote></td></tr>";
    }

    echo "<tr><td width='50%'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward' aria-hidden='true'></span> <a class='hover' href='category-" . $kbc_ID . "'>View All Items</a><br><br></td></tr>";
    echo "</table>";

    echo "</td>";
    }
    echo "</tr></table>";
```

Below is what the above code looks like on my website.

[image: This is what the above code looks like on my website]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this one, used 2 divs with 50% width as per your design in future if you need 3 or 4 column you can adjust. and its not necessary to have even no of category ?!!

// show all categories and split two categories onto each row

```
  echo "<div class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
$sql3 = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT ID, category FROM knowledgebase_category ORDER BY category");
while ($row3 = $sql3->fetch_assoc()){

                                    $kbc_ID = $row3['ID'];
                                    $kbc_category = $row3['category'];

                                    echo "<div width='50%' valign='top' style='float:left;'><h4 class='heading'>" . $row3['category'] . "</h4>";

                                        echo "<table class='' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>";
                                            $sql3a = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT kb_ID, kb_subject FROM knowledgebase_items WHERE kb_visible = 'Yes' and kb_category = '$kbc_ID' ORDER BY kb_subject LIMIT 5");
                                            while ($row3a = $sql3a->fetch_assoc()){
                                                echo "<tr><td width='50%'><blockquote class='message'><a class='hover' href='" . $row3a['kb_ID'] . "'>" . $row3a['kb_subject'] . "</a></blockquote></td></tr>";
                                            }   
                                                echo "<tr><td width='50%'><span class='glyphicon glyphicon-forward' aria-hidden='true'></span> <a class='hover' href='category-" . $kbc_ID . "'>View All Items</a><br><br></td></tr>";
                                        echo "</table>";

                                    echo "</div>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: please html elements as i don't have data so tested with dummy and looks perfect.

Comment: Yes this works great. Its very simply laid out how you did, thanks for your time !